Does the Microsoft Graph/Teams API give access to read Recap / AI notes?
I am using Teams Premium and I can see the Recap / AI note in the UI; but, I am unable to get these with the Graph API.
I would like to be able to get the Recap / AI notes as I can transcripts. https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/onlineMeetings/{id}/transcripts
Any pointers appreciated.
